# Lookup field: Need different value on opportunity

Tags: lookup

I  have an opportunity setting where the user needs to select a previous opportunity via a lookup field (The relationship field allows users to click on a lookup icon to select a value from a popup list. The other object is the source of the values in the list.). Works.
But now I need to display the number from this selected previous opportunity in a different field also on this opportunity.

How can I achieve that?

Kind regards
Alex
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to display some field from previous opportunity to your current opportunity record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a formula field to get this value. In the formula editor, select the Insert field option and select the lookup field and then the required field on that record.
[image: Formula field example]

Comment: Hi Apoorva, to easy to be obvious :)
Thanks. Works like a charm.